# How to implement multi resource authorization with Azure Application Registration?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-devops, authorization

I am facing an issue with the authentication configuration in my .NET 6 web application (OAuth 2 with Authorization Code flow). I have decided to implement authentication through Azure Application Registration. After adding the necessary platform, redirect URLs, scope everything worked like a charm. The business logic in my .NET application requires a connection to the Azure DevOps platform API, so I wanted to use the same Azure app reg to configure DevOps API authorization, so I added API permission for Azure DevOps. My intention was to use the same Bearer for authorization in my app and later in Azure DevOps API within the context of logged users, so in my swagger, I added two scopes:

```
api://tenantid/custom_scope_name                        // my custom scope
499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/user_impersonation // const azure devops scope
```

After that, I encountered the following error:
`AADSTS28003: Provided value for the input parameter scope cannot be empty when requesting an access token using the provided authorization code. Please specify a valid scope.`

I found out Microsoft does not allow specifying scopes for more than one resource, so I started to look for how to resolve that issue. I came across two potential "workarounds", though their solidity is not yet clear to me.

Firstly, I could obtain an access token for Azure DevOps scope and disable audience validation in my app. This approach works, but it doesn't seem to be a recommended solution.

Secondly, I could obtain an access token to my custom app scope, authorize it within my app and additionally send a refresh token to my app. In this approach, I could acquire an access token to Azure DevOps API scope with a received refresh token.

Could someone advise how this scenario should be implemented to keep the high quality and security of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure AD won't let you get tokens for both your app and Azure DevOps at once. Here are some workarounds:

---

##### 1. **Get the Azure DevOps Token and Skip a Security Check**

- **Good**: Easy to implement.
- **Bad**: It's a bit risky because it skips a security check.

---

##### 2. **Use a Refresh Token for Multiple Tokens**

- **Good**: More secure. Think of refresh tokens as "reusable passes" to get new access without asking the user all over again.
- **Bad**: Takes a bit more to set up, and you've got to keep that refresh token safe.

---

##### 3. **On-Behalf-Of Flow (OBO)**

If your app wants to talk to Azure DevOps for a user, this method is handy.

- **Good**: Made for this situation and is safe.
- **Bad**: Can be a bit tricky to set up the first time.

**Steps**:

1. The user logs into your app.
2. Your app gets a token.
3. Your app uses that token to get a different token for Azure DevOps.

---

##### 4. **Get Two Tokens, One After the Other**

Basically, you're asking the user to log in twice: first for your app and then for Azure DevOps.

- **Good**: Keeps things separate.
- **Bad**: Might be a bit tedious for users since they might get asked for permission twice.

**Steps**:

1. The user logs into your app.
2. Then, they log into Azure DevOps.
3. Use the right token for the right task.

---

**Recommendation**: I'd suggest the **On-Behalf-Of Flow (OBO)**, which is the third option. It's a good fit if your app frequently communicates with Azure DevOps on behalf of a user. But all options can work, so choose what feels right for your needs.

[image: On Behalf Of]